# How to avoid from expose IP address directly in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am use bootstrap 4 for my development. Currently, I have created a variable in JS file which contain of API URL (IP Address). So there have a concern when Group IT checking my code and advise me to avoid from directly stated IP address in JS file since not secure and easily can be access.

So how to avoid from expose IP address directly in JS? I have google and they advise to use .env file but how to apply? Currently I apply like below.

Referral: [Javascript Environment Variables](https://dev.to/deammer/loading-environment-variables-in-js-apps-1p7p)

This is my main directory which contain a `index.php` file and `.git` repository

[image]

The website require me to install dotenv using `npm i dotenv` just like below.

[image]

So inside `.env` file I wrote this:

```
HOST = http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xx
```

and I put another code inside `index.js` file like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    require('dotenv').config();

    const hostname = process.env.HOST;
    
    console.log(hostname);

});
```

but I getting this error, how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Exposing an IP address isn't insecure. That's nonsense. What *is* true is that you probably shouldn't hardcode that but keep it *configurable*, and .env files are a decent way to do that, yes.

Comment: I have implement using `.env` but getting error as above. where should the `.env` file exactly need to stored?

Answer (score 3):

Your error is caused by you confusing Node.js and web browsers. Both are tools in which you can run programs written in JavaScript, but not the same programs.

As to your actual problem: If you want the web browser to contact a server, then you *have to give it the address*.

That could be the IP address. That could be a hostname that the browser can resolve to an IP address using DNS.

You can't keep the address of the server secret from the person who controls the browser the JS is running on.

You can proxy requests through a different server, but then you have to tell the user the address of the proxy server instead.

Ultimately: **You cannot protect your server by hiding its existence from the user who needs to use it.**